# Mapping/Quantizing floating point range [-1,1] to integers

Tags: matlab, math, octave

I want to port the very handy function [`uencode`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/uencode.html) Matlabs `signal` package over to C++.

`uencode` can be used to map a range of floating point to integers, based on powers of two, without clipping them off. See the following image:

[image: matlap uencode plot]

My current Octave implementation of the same function (which I want to later port to C++):

```
1;
function ret = uencode (u, n)
  val = power(2, n) - 1;
  ret = ((u / 2) * val) + (val / 2);
endfunction

u = -1:0.01:1;
y = uencode(u, 2);
plot(u, y, '..');
grid on
```

It produces the correct range, however, I struggle with getting the steps as smooth as `uencode`, neither `round`, nor `floor`, nor `ceil` gives me correct results.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: have you had a look at the uuencode patch for octave-forge signal? http://savannah.gnu.org/support/download.php?file_id=30815

Comment: @Andy I didn't. I only noticed uencode wasn't implemented in signals. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For e.g. `floor` to do what you want, the unrounded output range should be from 0 to almost 4, rather than from 0 to 3. The following code (tested in Matlab) does what you want.

```
function ret = uencode (u, n)
    % output range
    val = power(2,n) - 1;

    % map input to output
    ret = (u+1)*(val+1)/2;

    % truncate to integer
    ret = floor(ret);

    % handle u~1
    ret(u > (1-1e-12)) = power(2,n) - 1;
end
```

Since the input range is now mapped to [0,4] the input u=1 will give 4 as output, therefore the last expression sets any value close enough to 1 (within 1e-12 here) to the maximum output value.

**EDIT:** replace the last expression by the following to correctly handle inputs outside the [-1,1] range.

```
% handle u out of range
ret(u >= 1)  = power(2,n) - 1;
ret(u <= -1) = 0;
```

**EDIT2:** here's an image of the function with the above modification:
[image: uencode function with clipping]

Comment: Nice. Would you be willing to contribute that code to the Octave signal package?